# sub in R Corpus

Tags: r, tm

I downloaded files such as [this one](https://www.bundestag.de/blob/479996/8ce5824ebb507bec232085fdd3a30396/18200-data.txt) to put in a corpus, all including text like

> "Deutscher Bundestag
>
> Stenografischer Bericht
>
> 200. Sitzung
>
> Berlin, Freitag, den 11. November 2016
>
> Inhalt
>
> Tagesordnungspunkt 36:
> Dritte Beratung des von der Bundesregierung eingebrachten Entwurfs eines Vierten Gesetzes zur Änderung arzneimittelrechtlicher und anderer Vorschriften
> Drucksachen 18/8034, 18/8333, 18/8461 Nr. 1.5, 18/10280, 18/10056
>
> Präsident Dr. Norbert Lammert:    Nehmen Sie bitte Platz. Die Sitzung
> ist eröffnet.  Liebe Kolleginnen und Kollegen, ich begrüße Sie"

I want to cut off all text up to the start of the parliamentary debate.

If I do

```
test <- c("text from above")
test <- sub(".*Die Sitzung ist eröffnet\\.","",test)
```

That works, but if I use

```
for (j in seq(test))
{
  test[[j]] <- sub(".*Die Sitzung ist eröffnet\\.","",test[[j]])

}
```

for the Corpus I don't get any kind of change. Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: There is no tm::VCorpus in your code example, just a character vector. Try `<<-` instead of `<-`.

Comment: Sorry, I had not added the VCorpus. I wanted to edit it but I realized that if I simply create the vcorpus from a character vector it does work. Just not when I use txt files instead :/